# Why does realloc() fail where malloc() succeds in C?

Tags: c, linux, malloc, realloc, rhel6

On RHEL6, I'm facing a strange problem with realloc().  At some point in the program, realloc() returns NULL (the old pointer has an address and there's plently of memory available).  What's being allocated is 200 structure elements (structure below).  For some reason, when I do a realloc() instead, it works, but I then have to assign the old pointer to the new one.  Below is a simplified version of my code.

This is perhaps a server tuning issue more than a programming one.  What is your opinion?
Thanks.

```
//hearder file
typedef struct  {        /* Variable Node Detail Record */
   long     next;
   long     mask;
   char     *value;   
   // more stuff...
} NODETEST;

extern NODETEST *oldNodes;
extern NODETEST *newNodes;

//program
#define MAXSIZE 200

// do some stuff with oldNodes....

int alloc_nodes (void)
{
    // Allocate or grow the table
    oldNodes = (NODETEST *) malloc(MAXSIZE * sizeof(NODETEST));
    if( oldNodes == NULL ) {
            //handle exception...
            exit(1);
      }

    //oldNodes = (NODETEST *) realloc(oldNodes,MAXSIZE * sizeof(NODETEST)); // *** FAILS

    newNodes = (NODETEST *) realloc(oldNodes,MAXSIZE * sizeof(NODETEST));   // *** WORKS

    if( newNodes == NULL ){
        printf("errno=%d\n", errno );
    }else{
        oldNodes = newNodes;            }
}
```

Comment: Use `perror` when `realloc` or `malloc` (or `calloc`) fails.

Comment: use `perror` and show us what it returns

Comment: Does `free` on the old pointer work?

Comment: The line of code you say "*** WORKS" is using `realloc()`, not `malloc()`.  I assume that's a mistake?  It might be nice to copy./paste the code that you actually see the problem with.

Comment: I'd suggest using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) on the code; there might be more going wrong than you realize.

Comment: "but I then have to assign the old pointer to the new one." - You **have** to do that with realloc() too, not just malloc().

Comment: You might want to past your real code. You are missing a semicolon on the first `malloc`. Chances are, the bug is in the missing code.

Comment: If the only difference between "works" and "fails" is the `realloc` line being commented out or not, then your last `if` line is going to be reading an uninitialized `newNodes`.

Comment: Michael, yes, I meant realloc.

Comment: Clarification: the code first calls malloc(), then resizes with realloc().  @nos: good point.

Comment: @user3772839: The comments in your code suggest that `realloc` either "WORKS" or "FAILS" depending on which variable you save its result to? This is highly unrealistic. I don't believe the code you posted above accurately describes the situation you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first call `malloc` with a size S and then `realloc` with the same size S. This is wrong: you have to pass to  `realloc` the new wanted size (independently of the current size - it is not an increment). Here, there is a big chance `realloc` returns exactly the same pointer it received. BTW it is not clear why you want to do with a `malloc` immediately followed by a `realloc`. Gives us more detail.

If you want a dynamic table whose size auto-adjusts, you need to allocate an initial size storing its size in a variable (e.g. `alloc_size`) and keep the current number of occupied elements in another variable (e.g. `n_elem`) . When you add an element you increment this number. When the table is full reallocate it. Here is a sketch

```
NODETEST *newNodes = NULL;
int allocated_elem = 0;
int n_elem = 0;

#define ALLOC_INCR 200
```

then at each addition:

```
if (n_elem >= alloc_size) { // the first time realloc is as malloc since nodes == NULL
    alloc_size += ALLOC_INCR;
    nodes = (NODETEST *) realloc(nodes, alloc_size * sizeof(NODETEST));
    if (nodes == NULL) {
        //handle exception...
        exit(1);
    }
}
// add your element at nodes[n_elem]
n_elem++;
```

Recall that realloc acts like malloc when the received pointer is `NULL` (case of the first call). Thus it allocates the initial table. Subsequent calls reallocate it by adjusting the size with a constant increment (here 200). Some other schemes are possible for the enlargement of the table, for instance you can multiply the size by a factor (e.g. 2) starting from 32:

```
if (n_elem >= alloc_size) { // the first time realloc is as malloc since nodes == NULL
    alloc_size = (alloc_size == 0) ? 32 : alloc_size * 2;
```

Regarind the `FAIL` and `WORKS` comments: it is clear that if you assign `oldNodes` (in the `FAIL` code) then `newNodes` is not assigned and keeps its initial value which is zero (`NULL`) since it is declared as a global variable and not initialized (well I suppose, it is `extern` here). Thus the test `if (newNodes == NULL)` will probably fail.

Comment: your code is so close to the original one I have.  Acutally, in my code, realloc() uses a different size than the existing pointer is pointing at.  I should have made my example better, sorry, I just can't post the original code.  I'll work my examples in a better way in the future, there is so much great advice on this board by people like you.  Thanks again.